# Vlookup - Comma separated values in a cell

Tags: excel, vlookup

Trying to do a VLookup with multiple values separated by comma. I have attached a picture of the sample i was trying to do (it shows the formula that i have at the top, along with the the reference table)

[image]

Comment: flip your column F and G or use INDEX MATCH as VLOOKUP needs the lookup value in the most left column of the range.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641040/excel-vlookup-where-the-key-is-not-in-the-first-column/38641090#38641090

Comment: use: `=INDEX(F:F,MATCH("*"&B2&"*",G:G,0))`

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the column you are first looking at. VLOOKUP works from left to right. You are starting in column F when your search is for data in column G.

This will return value, but not the information in column F.

```
=VLOOKUP("*" & B2 & "*", G1:G2,1,FALSE)
```

EDIT: As per comments, you can flip the columns to make your original formula work.