# How to search through an array of rows for a partial string in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, ms-office

I am used to Excel but am still pretty new to more complex formulas. I am trying to fill in the id field in the data table automatically based on the name.

I have two tables, one is a list of employees, and another is a log of associates' actions.

Here is the ID list.

| `A5` ID | `A6` Name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Foo Bar |
| 321 | John Doe |
| 246 | Jane Doe |
| 135 | Mike Jones |

Here is the log list.

| `A1` ID | `A2` Name | `A3` Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | Jane Doe | xxxxx |
|  | John Doe | abcdefg |
|  | Jane Doe | zzzzz |
|  | Foo Bar | yyyyyyy |

I want to be able to take the current cell's index in the log and compare the name to the list of employees and copy the cell to the left of it to get the id.

Do you know of any formulas that would guide me to my goal?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641040/excel-vlookup-where-the-key-is-not-in-the-first-column/38641090#38641090

Comment: There are a LOT of new, incredibly valuable functions in newer Excel O365, and more on the way every few months.  But if you are doing these kinds of problems often, take just a few minutes and play with XLOOKUP, XMATCH and FILTER.  Out of the many new functions, those 3 will *change your life* if you are doing these kinds of exercises often.  Watch a couple if videos, build a couple of samples and tinker, and in less than an hour you will be the king of the world.  Once you are comfortable with them you will start using excel in all kinds of new use cases.