# Excel, if cell matches another cell then copy another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

[image]

I have information of column A,D and E.
I want to achieve result of column B

So I want a formula if any number of column A match any number of column E, the text on D column which is in same row as E number to moved on B column on right position.

*The numbers on all columns can't be reorder

Comment: INDEX/MATCH or XLOOKUP will do what you want.

Comment: Or, `FILTER()` if you are in `MS365` or `Excel 2021/19`

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641040/excel-vlookup-where-the-key-is-not-in-the-first-column/38641090#38641090

Comment: I have Excel 2010 so these formulas aren't available

Comment: [INDEX()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) & [MATCH()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) are available in `Excel 2010`

Comment: Please check the reference guide for the availability of **[Excel Functions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-by-category-5f91f4e9-7b42-46d2-9bd1-63f26a86c0eb)**

Comment: `=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A1,E:E,0))`

Comment: Just as an alternative to ^^^ --> `=VLOOKUP(A1,IF({1,0},E:E,D:D),2,0)` or `=VLOOKUP(A1,CHOOSE({1,2},E:E,D:D),2,0)` but are inefficient with respect to `INDEX()` with `MATCH()` --> Use `INDEX()` & `MATCH()` for better performance.